# Element is present but nightwatch.js not seeing element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

So i've been experimenting with NW and have found it is KISS(Keep It Stupid Simple)! I have ran into one problem though.

I am a freelance QA tester that has focused primarily on manual testing, however i'm branching out to automation to help speed up tasks at work.

The site i am currently testing has "2" steps when you navigate to it. The structure is as follows:
1: Navigate to URL
2: "subscribe page" displays containing a box to enter your email
3: Once email is enter, box changes to have user to enter their zipcode

When users are on the email section, if the email is not syntactically valid, it will contain a little X icon, if its valid, it contains a checkmark
The same is true for the zipcode section.

What am I testing: 
Both the invalid and valid icons for both the email and zip code display when they should.

I've broken my tests up into two segments. 1 for testing the email address icons, and 1 for testing the zip icons. 
I've gotten the email address tests written and they run perfectly, however the zip address keeps failing out for me.

Here is a block of code that i'm using for the zip code.

When running, i'm seeing:

```
    ✔  Element <#two_step_div> was present after 985 milliseconds.
    ✔  Testing if the page title equals "WEBSITE TITLE HERE".
    ✔  Element <#postal_code> was present after 14 milliseconds.s
    ✖  Timed out while waiting for element <input[class="js-zip js-success"]> to be present for 10000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: not found


'This is checking valid zip icon is present': function (browser) {
    browser
        .url("WEBSITE_URL HERE")
        .waitForElementPresent("#two_step_div", 8000)
        .assert.title('WEBSITE TITLE HERE')
        .setValue('input[type=text]', ['test@example.com', browser.Keys.ENTER])
        .waitForElementPresent("#postal_code", 10000)
        .setValue('input[type=text]', '12345')
        .waitForElementVisible('input[class="js-zip js-success"]', 10000)
        .end();
    };
```

It seems like its just skipping over the .setValue line as it doesn't even seem like its adding the "12345" zipcode that i'm specifyings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Mac OS X(10.9.5)

Comment: I am not familiar with that api. But do you know if there is any way to pass `clear` on the text field?

Comment: Here you go. Add this
`client.clearValue('input[type=text]');` right before ` .setValue('input[type=text]', '12345')`

Comment: Yes its possible for a clear by using .clearValue(). Would you recommend .waitForElementPresent to trigger, then run the clearValue then set the value?

Comment: Now that I took a look again I see the selector you are using for zip code is wrong. See my answer below

Comment: Definitely solved my problem. 

If you care to answer a quick question, why would the selector be different from the one used in the email setValue?

Comment: Couple of possible reasons. The way your elements is being Identified can be different. Plus, `input[type=text]` may not be a valid selector for zip code field. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox to inspect element and see how those elements are originally designed

Comment: awesome! super helpful! If only i could give you more rep!

Comment: You can give my answer a thumbs up :D

Comment: I've only got 7 rep....can't do it until i get 15. Once i get to 15, ill definitely be coming back here and tossing a +1 :)

Comment: It's all good. I am glad that I was able to help you.

Comment: And don't forget to check out [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) which is another great toll for finding selector from FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'This is checking valid zip icon is present': function (browser) {
    browser
        .url("WEBSITE_URL HERE")
        .waitForElementPresent("#two_step_div", 8000)
        .assert.title('WEBSITE TITLE HERE')
        .setValue('input[type=text]', ['test@example.com', browser.Keys.ENTER])
        .waitForElementPresent("#postal_code", 10000)
        .setValue('#postal_code', '12345')
        .waitForElementVisible('input[class="js-zip js-success"]', 10000)
        .end();
    };
```